# Leaflet: Centering map when zoom in

Tags: leaflet, d3

For a project I have to use four sets of JSON datas (and one of the files is bigger than 10M).

I am loading these files asynchronously using queue.js. Once it's fully loaded and displayed I am meeting two problems.

Firstly, there is no animation when I zoom in or out the window. It's jerky and laggy. Secondly when I tried to zoom with the mouse the the zoom is systematically centered in the top-left corner.

I self-hosted my code here:
http://adrienrahier.com/test/SFmap/

you can found the sources here: https://github.com/FracArt/ChallengeSF

Comment: No time to look into this right now, but whith all the JSON data you are loading a jerky and laggy experience is what you would expect!

Comment: it's part of the specifications unfortunately. By the way, I am interested if you have another solution to offer.

Comment: If the specification is about loading huge amounts of vector data, then I do not think there are very good solutions yet, but as you are already using d3, have a look at: [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) and [bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5593150)...

Comment: I will take a look at bl.ocks. Thank you for your answer :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check these code blocks from Mike Bostock.

1. [Click to zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590), please also check the comments on this example, links to another series of examples.
2. [Zoomable Geography](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2374239)